# Find bem class and replace by another

Tags: jquery

I search variant how with jQuery find BEM modificatory in `<div>` with more classes, eg.

```
<div class="xc-icon xs-icon--account-circle xs-font--big">
```

I need detect to modificator `xs-icon--account-circle` but `accoutn-cicle` is variable, so I need detect only `xs-icon--something-sometimes-with-dash`

Can somebody help my how maybe via regular expression detect only variable BEM modificatory?

Thank you.

Comment: Any tried? So far

Comment: The 'attribute contains' selector may help you if you don't need to know what the part following `xs-icon--` is: `$('div[class*="xs-icon--"]');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following, it will look an element that contains a specific part of a class and remove the class.

```
$("[class*=xs-icon--]").removeClass(function(index, className) {
  return (className.match(/(^|\s)xs-icon--\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
});
```

`$("[class*=xs-icon--]")` = if any element contains a class with `xs-icon--`

if you run the code `class="xc-icon xs-icon--account-circle xs-font--big"` would return `class="xc-icon xs-font--big"`

```js
$("[class*=xs-icon--]").removeClass(function(index, className) {
  return (className.match(/(^|\s)xs-icon--\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="xc-icon xs-icon--account-circle xs-font--big">test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass jQuery a CSS "contains" selector, e.g.

`$("[class*='xs-icon--']")`

This should return you a collection of all the xs-icon elements that have a BEM modifier.